# Lost sound with xmonad

Tags: ubuntu, audio, alsa, xmonad

I downloaded [this config](https://github.com/vicfryzel/xmonad-config) to set up xmonad. Hit volume up, down, works fine. Hit the volume mute hotkey, sound's gone. All good. Hit the mute key again, sound's still off. Hit volume up, nothing. `alsamixer` looks fine it seems, "Master" and "Headphone" are both non-zero. Restarted computer, sound still off. The lock screen before I log into xmonad does make a sound though, so clearly the sound is still working.

Any ideas how I can get my sound turned back on when using xmonad?

**EDIT** sound works fine when I log in using Unity. Very weird

**EDIT 2** `speaker-test` produces no sound

Comment: The key shortcut is calling `amixer -q set Master toggle`, do you get an error if you run it from a terminal ? In alsamixer, when muted the bar aren't at zero, there is a `MM` at  the bottom (and you type m to mute/unmute).

Comment: @Leiaz Nope, no error, and `alsamixer` shows `00`/`MM` accordingly when I press the hotkey, so that seems to be working fine...

Comment: Did you only used the Al+Ctrl+M shortcut defined in XMonad or also an actual mute button or sound widget ? You are probably using Pulseaudio on top of alsa ? Could you have muted Pulseaudio at some point ?

Comment: @Leiaz yes, I only used the shortcut defined in XMonad, and pulseaudio seems to be running, but I don't see how I could've muted it

Answer (score 8):

Finally fixed it by going through absolutely every bar in alsamixer, even the ones that I wasn't sure would matter, and unmuting them all. As it turns out, the mute toggle mutes everything, but only unmutes the master volume.